# Weekly Summary in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create weekly summary for my employees.

Below is how my DATA looks.

[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbbNy.png)

To create weekly summary i tried PIVOT table and got the results. Below is how the summary looks[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQval.png).

The issue here is i want data from Monday till sunday. But the weeknum formula is giving me data for sunday to monday. Can anyone help me with a fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weeknum for June 2, 2021 gives 23
but `=weeknum("June 2, 2021",21)` gives 22, because the week begins Monday in that system. See https://support.google.com/docs/thread/64174872/hi-is-weeknum-returning-the-wrong-week-in-2021-in-sheets-weeknum-25-01-2021-2-gives-5?hl=en